# How to show all posts of specific custom post type with their custom fields values?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field

I am trying to get the list of all posts with `post_type` "**staff**" along with custom fields assigned to this `post_type`. Custom fields were create with help of ACF.

I've tried both:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array (
    'post_type'      => 'staff',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
) );

$staff = $query->get_posts();
```

and

```
$args  = array (
    'post_type'      => 'staff',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
);

$staff = get_posts( $args );
```

which returns the list of posts, but doesn't list their custom fields.

What is the best performance-wise way to get all the post names with corresponding custom fields? I've been looking for hours now but only getting more and more confused...

Comment: You mean [meta query](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/221169/how-to-show-all-posts-of-specific-custom-post-type-with-their-custom-fields-valu) ?

Comment: @Sumit not sure how to use it for my case

Answer (score 0):

The meta information is in a different db table from my understanding. What you'll need to do is loop through each post and grab it's meta data using [`get_fields()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_fields/).

Below is a sample from the query to find all the fields for a particular post.

```
$rows = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT option_name, option_value FROM $wpdb->options WHERE option_name LIKE %s OR option_name LIKE %s",
    $post_id . '_%' ,
    '_' . $post_id . '_%' 
), ARRAY_A);

if( !empty($rows) ) {

    foreach( $rows as $row ) {

        $meta[ $row['option_name'] ][] = $row['option_value'];

    }

}
```

A SQL wiz might be able to merge the two which would be great, but until then, stick with [`get_fields`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_fields/).